# Display data dump used in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer

Is there anywhere on the Data Explorer that stipulates the data dump that it currently using? If not I wonder if it woul dbe a good an idea to put this information somewhere on the site.

Also, I see the [Creative Commons Data Dump Jun ’11](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-11/) has been released but I'm seeing some unexpected differences (I would expect some differences) between the live site and data site. Is there a lag between when the data dump is made available and when SEDE hooks up to it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/16858/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives you the date of the data on the front page for each site

[image: Data Dump Dates]

Comment: Freehand circles!